# Trying to populate choices in drop down on PowerApps based on SharePoint People Picker field

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApps app that connects to a SharePoint list. There is a column, Approver, that I want to use to filter a report. Approver is a People Picker field. I want to have a drop-down input box on my PowerApps screen that has the names of Approvers from the SharePoint list, so that I can filter the results based on approvers rather than typing in a name from the GAL. Is this possible, and if so, any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can display Approvers in a dropdown:

Collect all values from the Approver field. We want to only take "DisplayName". But you can also take an email if you wish. We collect all of these values in the `Approvers` array:

```
ClearCollect(ContractsList, Contracts);
Collect(Approvers,ForAll(ContractsList, 'Approver'.DisplayName));
```

Now you can simply use the `Approvers` array as a data source for a dropdown:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mijls.png]

Next, you can filter your table or a galery based on the selected value in your dropdown.